# Why javascript comparision number incorrect?

Tags: javascript

Why javascript comparision number incorrect ?

It's very simple but why incorrect (alert `false`)?

```
<script>
  var xxx = "112.77";
  alert(xxx);
  if(xxx < '2.50')
  {
      alert("false");     
  }
  else
  {
      alert("true");          
  }
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sp82ehqp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert at least one to number with an [unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) and compare then.

Strings are compared by character for character.

As you see, if one of the value is a number, the comparison is made by number.

```js
var xxx = "112.77";
console.log(xxx);
console.log(xxx < '2.50');   // true
console.log(+xxx < +'2.50'); // false
console.log(xxx < +'2.50');  // false
console.log(+xxx < '2.50');  // false
```

Answer (score 2):

> That's because your using String, rather  than a number. **Just remove
>   the `""`**.

Here's your [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sp82ehqp/1/)

```js
  var x = 112.77;
  alert(x);
  if (x < 2.50) {
    alert(false);
  } else {
    alert(true);
  }
```

---

**Dynamic Data Types in JavaScript**

In JavaScript numbers, strings and Booleans are identified by their punctuation. e.g.:

```
var foo = 42;    // foo is now a Number
var foo = 'bar'; // foo is now a String
var foo = true;  // foo is now a Boolean
```

[Read more about JavaScript basic data types](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp)

---

**Converting Strings to Numbers**

If your unable to define your number as a number (e.g. your pulling it from an input field). Then you can convert it using **[`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)**. If your number is an integer, you can also use **[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)**.

```
Number('123')     // 123
Number('12.3')    // 12.3
Number('')        // 0
Number('0x11')    // 17
Number('0b11')    // 3
Number('0o11')    // 9
Number('foo')     // NaN
Number('100a')    // NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript will do type conversion if one of the objects is a number and the other is a string. So if for some reason your `xxx` variable is a string all you have to do is change the type of `2.50`:

```
 var xxx = "112.77";


  alert(xxx);
  if(xxx < 2.50 )
  {
      alert("false");     
  }
  else
  {
      alert("true");          
  }
```

Comment: *"it uses the first object as the base type"* - Nope. If either value is a number JS tries to coerce the other value to a number.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure it was the first object.

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing strings, parse them to Number

```
var xxx = 112.77;
  alert(xxx);
  if(xxx < 2.50)
  {
     alert("false");     
 }
 else
  {
  alert("true");
```

}

Comment: *"parse them to integer"* - But they're not integers.

Comment: to Number sorry

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing string.

```
 var xxx = 112.77;
  alert(xxx);
  if(xxx < 2.50)
  {
      alert("false");     
  }
  else
  {
      alert("true");          
  }
```